# docker-compose selenium-grid, maven, java. Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities

Tags: java, maven, selenium, docker, selenium-grid

I'm trying to run selenium java project in docker containers:

my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59-vanadium
    container_name: hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:3.141.59-vanadium
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444

  mongo:
    image: 'mongo:4.0.4'
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - 'mongo:/data/db'

  app:
    image: app:latest
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - firefox

volumes:
  mongo:
```

my Dockerfile for java app:

```
#
# Build stage
#
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app

# build jar with dependencies
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean compile assembly:single

#
# Package stage
#
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar /usr/local/lib/app.jar
EXPOSE 5001
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/app.jar", "docker"]
```

plugins from pom.xml:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>7</source>
                <target>7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>learn.selenium.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>learn.selenium.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>learn.selenium.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Connecting to selenium from code:

```
Capabilities firefoxCapabilities = new FirefoxOptions();
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://hub:4444/wd/hub"), firefoxCapabilities);
```

When I'm trying to run the docker compose with only selenium stuff, it looks like it works fine. But when I'm adding java app to container, I'm getting the following error:

```
hub        | org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, moz:firefoxOptions: {args : {}}}
hub        |    at org.openqa.grid.internal.ProxySet.verifyAbilityToHandleDesiredCapabilities(ProxySet.java:146)
...
app_1  | org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, moz:firefoxOptions: {args: [], prefs: {}}}
app_1  | Command duration or timeout: 453 milliseconds
app_1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Here is the grid console:
[image: http://localhost:4444/grid/console]

Could you advice what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can add the healthcheck for grid status https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#waiting-for-the-grid-to-be-ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems, that the hub wasn't ready while I've tried to connect to it. So for testing I added Thread.sleep(1000) and it worked. The correct way here I suppose is to ping the hub and proceed with web driver initialization once the status is changed to ready. 
For me it's quite strange, because I added

```
 depends_on:
  - mongo
  - firefox
```

So I expected my java project to be run after the selenium related containers are up and ready.